# Convergence of the sum of columns/rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a real invertible $N\times N$ matrix, and $O$ the $N\times N$ matrix with all the entries equal to 1.
Define the $\epsilon$ dependent matrix $A(\epsilon)$ as
$$
A(\epsilon) = O + \epsilon B,\quad \epsilon\in\Bbb R.
$$

$A(\epsilon)$ is invertible for each $\epsilon\neq0$, so we can let $C(\epsilon)$ be the inverse of $A(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon\neq0$.
As $\epsilon\to0$ the matrix $A(\epsilon)$ converges to $O$, so clearly $C(\epsilon)$ diverges as $\epsilon\to0$.  Anyways, it happens that both the sum of the rows and the sum of the columns of $C(\epsilon)$ converge as $\epsilon\to0$.  I have clear numerical evidence of this fact, but I don't know how to formally prove it.  Can you help me?

Comment: $A(\epsilon)$ is not invertible for every $\epsilon\ne 0$...

Comment: @Exodd Yes, you're right.  Probably is it for $\epsilon$ small enough?

Comment: Anyhow, suppose it is invertible.  Then the stated result should hold.

Comment: Notice that $O$ is a rank one matrix, so you can write the inverse of $O+\epsilon B$ with  the Sherman-Morrison formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $O = ee^T$, where $e$ is the all ones vector. As a consequence, if you suppose everything is invertible, you can use the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula and get
$$
(O + \epsilon B)^{-1}e = (\epsilon B)^{-1}e - \frac{(\epsilon B)^{-1}ee^T(\epsilon B)^{-1}}{1+e^T(\epsilon B)^{-1}e}e
\\=
\frac 1{1+e^T(\epsilon B)^{-1}e}
(\epsilon B)^{-1}e \\
=\frac 1{\epsilon+e^TB^{-1}e}
B^{-1}e
$$
This quantity explodes only if $e^TB^{-1}e = 0$, so to get a counterexample, take for example
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you will get sum of row/columns of the order $O(1/\epsilon)$.

Comment: Very good, thank you